Как убрать выделение у объектов при нажатии с телефона? (css)
Как убрать обводку у элемента при нажатии. Я использую html, css и js. Пример обводки вокруг монеты:


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Вот без обводки

Вы можете убрать цвет у выделения таким образом:
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;

Добавьте это в свой css чтобы убрать выделение со всех элементов:
* {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

Источник решения
Дополнительная информация

Но не работает всё равно вот ссылка https://frabjous-fairy-d0a4b7.netlify.app. заходите через телефон и посмотрите

@MineNot попробуйте применить это свойство ко всем элементам через селектор *

Все сработало спасибо большое
